# SQL Select Multiple FIelds from Multiple Data Issue

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql query

```
SELECT content_type_clients.nid, content_type_clients.field_logo_display_value,
files.filepath, node.title, node.created 
  FROM content_type_clients, files, node 
WHERE content_type_clients.nid=node.nid 
AND files.fid=content_type_clients.field_client_logo_fid 
  ORDER BY field_logo_display_value DESC, node.created ASC
```

But some of the fields won't have a `files.fid=content_type_clients.field_client_logo_fid` value. Is there a way to see if files.fid and content_type_clients.field_client_logo_fid have a value (not NULL) and if it is NULL don't do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the fields don't match (or have a NULL) value, your query won't return results. So if it's NULL, it doesn't do it.

Your query

```
SELECT content_type_clients.nid, content_type_clients.field_logo_display_value, files.filepath, node.title, node.created FROM content_type_clients, files, node WHERE content_type_clients.nid=node.nid AND files.fid=content_type_clients.field_client_logo_fid ORDER BY field_logo_display_value DESC, node.created ASC
```

is actually an older way (ANSI-89) of writing the more modern (ANSI-92)

```
SELECT content_type_clients.nid, content_type_clients.field_logo_display_value, files.filepath, node.title, node.created 
FROM content_type_clients 
JOIN files ON files.fid=content_type_clients.field_client_logo_fid 
JOIN node ON content_type_clients.nid=node.nid 
ORDER BY field_logo_display_value DESC, node.created ASC
```

Now if you want the query to return results even when the files do not match, use a LEFT OUTER JOIN instead:

```
SELECT content_type_clients.nid, content_type_clients.field_logo_display_value, files.filepath, node.title, node.created 
FROM content_type_clients 
JOIN node ON content_type_clients.nid=node.nid 
LEFT OUTER JOIN files ON files.fid=content_type_clients.field_client_logo_fid 
ORDER BY field_logo_display_value DESC, node.created ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

`files.fid IS NOT NULL`

in your `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

If they have null values, they'd never be caught in the join operation. In SQL, null cannot ever be equal to anything, including itself.

```
SELECT ..
FROM ...
WHERE x = null
```

will always return nothing, because you cannot test for equality with null. Instead, you have to use the special

```
WHERE x IS null
```

syntax

Answer (score 0):

This should also work. It only selects files that exist and are in the content_type_clients table.

```
SELECT content_type_clients.nid, content_type_clients.field_logo_display_value,     
files.filepath, node.title, node.created
  FROM files left outer join content_type_clients on files.fid=content_type_clients.field_client_logo_fid 
    left outer join node on content_type_clients.nid=node.nid 
ORDER BY field_logo_display_value DESC, node.created ASC
```